# how to log multiple dates and time in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database, inside this database. I have every **subscription** and **badge** and I'd like to log everytime a badge or a **subscription** is been used.

## This is my database :

| id | badge | validateat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | badge1 | 2022-03-22 02:24:25 |
| 2 | badge2 | 2022-03-22 02:24:25 |
| 3 | subscription1 | 2022-01-22 10:20:15 |

Can I log everytime a badge is validated inside "validateat" or I have to create a table for every badge and subscription?

Comment: can you add more details of what you want because I don't understand it at all

Comment: Do you mean every time the table is read or something more specific?

Comment: Imagine a building where every employee has its own badge to open the automated gate. I want to log everytime the employee opens the gate. Can I do it using my database or I have to create a table for every badge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a table to log badge activity.

```
create table badges (
  id integer primary key auto_increment,
  name varchar(255) not null,
  validated_at datetime not null
);

create table badge_activities (
  badge_id integer not null,
    index(badge_id),
    foreign key(badge_id) references badges,
  activity_at datetime not null
)
```

Then insert into badge_activities every time you want to log something.

```
insert into badge_activities (badge_id, activity_at) values (3, current_timestamp)
```

You can also add a column to describe the activity. This could be a varchar, an [enum](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html), or a foreign key to another table of activites.

However, unless you need to query this data consider writing to a log file and using a log indexing service instead.